Element pins when scrolling upwards but not when scrolling downwards - GSAP
I'm trying to create a basic GSAP pin element. It pins but only when I scroll upward. I would also like it to pin when I scroll downward on a component.
Like when I get to the location component on a page the cta-container remains pinned while I scroll through the component and ends when I scroll past the component. Like it should appear over the .container div content while scrolling.
Here is how I did:
    stickFloor: function () {
      gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

      const height = $(".location .container").outerHeight();

      ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: ".location__cta-container",
        start: "top top",
        end: "+=" + height,
        pin: ".location__cta-container",
        pinSpacing: false,
      });

    },

.location {
  padding-bottom: 48px;

  &__cta-container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    background-color: white;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  &__cta-mobile {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 24px;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

<section class="location"">
  <div class="location__cta-container d-block d-lg-none">
    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#floor-modal" data-index="" class="location__cta-mobile button">View <?php echo $name; ?> Floor Plans</a>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
        <div class="location__left">
          <div class="location__about">
            <h3 class="location__heading">About <?php echo $name; ?></h3>
            <p class="location__desc"><?php echo $short_description; ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="location__rates">
            <div class="location__eyebrow-text">Rates</div>
            <div class="location__rates-list">
              <div class="location__rate">
                <div class="location__sub-title">Price</div>
    <!--..remaining content..//-->


